# Python graphing with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Okay so I'm trying to plot a function with an e to some expression but I keep getting an error at the lines that I have put (##) @ where the error message is

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'numpy.ufunc' and 'float'

```
#!C:\Users\msawe\Anaconda3 or C:\Anaconda3\python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure (figsize=(10,10), dpi=100)

ax = plt.subplot(111)

plt.title('Projectile Motion: Goround given by h(x) ', size=24)

ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data',0))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data',0))

def h(x):
"This function will return the y-coordinate for a given x-coordinate launch."
##return 1 - np.exp(-1* x/1000) + 0.28 *( 1 - np.exp(-0.038*x**2))*(1 - np.cos*(20*x**0.2))

X = np.linspace(0, 10, 101, endpoint=True)  

##plt.plot(X, h(X), color="black", linewidth=3, linestyle="-", label="h(x)")

plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(0,10,11,endpoint=True))

plt.ylim(0,20.0)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(0,20,11,endpoint=True))

plt.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=False)
plt.savefig("Ch5_P4_lowRes.png",dpi=60)
plt.savefig("Ch5_P4_hiRes.png",dpi=200)
plt.savefig("Ch5_P4_plotting.pdf",dpi=72)

plt.show()
```

If I could just get a general idea on how to make it work that would be great.

Comment: matplotlib probably expects the second argument to plot as a array of values, not a function/ufunc. Internal operations might need some operators defined on this like * which works on an array, but not on a custom-function. Generate an array a-priori from your function and try again (maybe it would work too by using [np.vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html))!

Comment: You have a typo: "np.cos*(" should just be "np.cos("

Comment: Tracebacks always include the line number(s) the error occurred on. All you needed to do was look at the line at the bottom of the traceback and carefully examine your code on it, and you would have caught the typo. Next time, please include the **full text** of the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I'm interpreting your equation correctly, there's a bug in your implementation of `np.cos()` in your definition of h(x): you wrote `np.cos*(...)` rather than `np.cos(...)`. After fixing that, the code is able to plot- hopefully it's giving the right result!

This would turn your definition of h(x) from:

```
def h(x):
    return 1 - np.exp(-1* x/1000) + 0.28 *( 1 - np.exp(-0.038*x**2))*(1 - np.cos*(20*x**0.2))
```

Into:

```
def h(x):
    return 1 - np.exp(-1* x/1000) + 0.28 *( 1 - np.exp(-0.038*x**2))*(1 - np.cos(20*x**0.2))
```

The difference is subtle but important! You can easily check for bugs like this by running successively smaller segments of your code to see which operation is throwing the error- this let me quickly hone in on the `np.cos*(...)` typo.

Comment: Tracebacks always include the line number of the error. All the OP needed to do was read the full error message and carefully examine the lines listed, as well as the lines before them.